# How to sum values of rows based of query in another column of that row?

Tags: google-sheets

In the table below, I'd like to write a query in each `{calc}` cell that will use the `name` column to look up a value and sum the column based off the percentage in each cell.

For example for each row in `month1`, `month2`, `month3`, etc., I'd like to query another sheet based off the `name` and then sum up the results.

I'm less worried about the math or the query itself, but more interested in how to reference a index/iteration of a query to sum up all the rows. During a `SUM` operation, is there a way to reference the current index/row being summed and make a query based off that?

```
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|         name         |    month1    |    month2    |   month 3    |
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|                      | {calc-1}     | {calc-2}     | {calc-3}     |
| name1                | 65%          | 100%         | 85%          |
| name2                | 100%         | 100%         | 90%          |
| name3                | 100%         | 100%         | 80%          |
+----------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Example sheet where formulas could be run.

```
+-------+--------+
| name  | number |
+-------+--------+
| name1 |     10 |
| name2 |     20 |
| name3 |      5 |
+-------+--------+
```

The output for `{calc-1}` would be the SUM of 65% of 10, 100% of 20, 100% 0f 5 and so on.  `calc-1 = 31.5` And I'd like to run this for each month.

Comment: can you provide example of desired output? or copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 I added an example table to the question.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if A3:A5 = A10:A12, you can do this formula in B2

```
=arrayformula(query(B3:D5*B10:B12,"select Sum(Col1), Sum(Col2), Sum(Col3) label Sum(Col1) '', Sum(Col2) '', Sum(Col3) ''"))
```

Else, you must change as your actual range, so A3:A5=A10:A12

The Result:

| 31.5  |  35 | 30.5 |

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Can these query across two separate sheets?  All the sheets are created from API calls or other advanced formulas, so I cannot write a quiery the works on just a single sheet.  I cannot guarentee the name colum will be in the same order, so I need to vlookup or match on the other sheet?

Comment: yes surely, you can change B10:B12 to yoursheet!B2:B4

Comment: and you can also use api

Comment: but if the order is not the same and I'm trying to match by name, how does that work?

Comment: if not same order, may be you can order first, or you can use vlookup from current sheet to source sheet

Comment: Im not sure how to ue vlookup in the `data` arg in `query` call.  Is that possible?  I can alternatively make another couple columns to use vlookup.

Comment: you have solved my initial question, thank you.  I now realize my `calc-1` cells are more complicated than my minimal example. is one able to do any more arithmetic in the data arg `query(B3:D5*B10:B12` ?  For example maybe I need to inverse the percentage or modify the values in B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206584/discussion-between-user11982798-and-wprater).

Answer (score 0):

you can use mmult and vlookup:

```
=arrayformula(mmult(COLUMN(B1:D1)^0,(B3:D5*vlookup(A3:A5,A10:B12,2,0))))
```

[image]